# How to make a RESTEasy Response Filter?

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm having trouble trying to make RESTEasy Filters work. I'm sure that I'm missing something, but I don't know what.

I'm testing with the following method:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<User> listAll(@QueryParam("start") Integer startPosition, @QueryParam("max") Integer maxResult) {
    String hql = "SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.tasks ORDER BY u.id";
    TypedQuery<User> findAllQuery = em.createQuery(hql, User.class);
    if (startPosition != null) {
        findAllQuery.setFirstResult(startPosition);
    }
    if (maxResult != null) {
        findAllQuery.setMaxResults(maxResult);
    }
    final List<User> results = findAllQuery.getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

And here's my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="3.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>tasks-webapp</display-name>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>ico</extension>
        <mime-type>image/x-icon</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <context-param> 
        <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>br.com.tasks.rest.CORSFilter</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And finally, my Filter:

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

   @Override
   public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                      final ContainerResponseContext cres) throws IOException {
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
   }

}
```

With this combined It's not working. I left an breakpoint in the filter and it's never called. And I'm testing with Postman and my headers are missing. I saw other questions here and I followed it's instructions without success. I tried with the Application class and nothing too.

Someone help me? I'm grateful in advance. :)

Comment: Did you managed to fix this?

Comment: I had a similar problem with a RESTEasy Request filter.   It would not run.   I solved the problem by specifying the filter in the class that extends Application.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding:

```
<context-param> 
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

To register your providers as explained [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html_single/#d4e125) ? Because it seems that default value is `false`

Comment: I will try this as soon as I can and report the result. Thank's.

Comment: No success. I put this code in web.xml but my filter still does not call and the headers in postman are missing. Got any other trick?